# compare 2 data frames based on 3 columns and update second data

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Here are my data frames looks like. Need to compare based on if df1.mid = df2.mid & df1.name=df2.name & df1.pid != df2.pid then update df2.pid with df1.pid.

df1

```
mid pid name
1   2   John
2   14  Peter
3   16  Emma
4   20  Adam
```

df2

```
mid pid name
1   2   John
2   16  Peter
3   16  Emma
```

expected result in df2 after update

```
mid pid name
1   2   John
2   14  Peter
3   16  Emma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `merge` is what you want but there are some finesse to take into account:

```
df2.merge(df1, on=['mid', 'name'], how='left', suffixes=('_2', '_1')) \
    .assign(pid=lambda x: x['pid_1'].combine_first(x['pid_2'])) \
    .drop(columns=['pid_1', 'pid_2'])
```

- `merge` aligns `df1` and `df2` based on `mid` and `name`. The two `pid` columns are renamed `pid_1` and `pid_2`.
- `assign` creates a new `pid` column by combining the two previous `pid`s: if `pid_1` is available, use that, if not, keep the original `pid_2`
- `drop` drops `pid_1` and `pid_2`, leaving one and only one `pid` column

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
df3= df1.join(df2,on=['mid','name','pid'],how='right')
```